# How do I commit my changes following a git revert of my previous commit?

Tags: git

I had to revert the "git push" that I had done earlier. Since that revert on mainline, I have not pulled code and haven't committed anything. I still have all the reverted code on my system and additional changes. What is the best way to go about committing the code without losing any of my changes?

Comment: You don't revert a *push*, in Git; you revert a specific commit. To put it back again afterwards, you can revert the revert, or do any number of other things, but "revert the revert" tends to be what people use. But if you meant you used `git push --force` to *remove* a commit, that's quite a different scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could amend that revision (without any changes), so that git sees it as something that has not been merged, then you could rebase.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```